# odata service query Page Content

Tags: odata, api

I am trying to query a published page content by invoking the below odata service url.

http://host:port/odata.svc/PageContents(PageId=172261,PublicationId=311)

in the response i see only the links to the related items "" and some other properties "". Can someone help with the below question please?

- Is there a way to retrieve content of the published page (lets say the page includes 2 component presentation) through odata service url? If yes what query parameters need to be added to the url?

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like the Page is published to the file system instead of DB. OData only uses the database to return content, so first check if you're storing the page in the Database.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the ComponentPresentations included in a Page with odata, the url would be:

```
http://host:port/odata.svc/Pages(ItemId=172261,PublicationId=311)/ComponentPresentations
```

Answer (score 2):

if its published to Database as @Nuno Suggested above try following command.

```
http://host:port/odata.svc/Pages(ItemId=172261,PublicationId=311)/ComponentPresentations
```